# How to return multiple components for each element in a array using map()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps-api-3, jsx

I tried to do it in this way.
I want to return multiple `<LocationMarker>` for each "ev". But it's only returning one `<LocationMarker>` for each "ev". for loop inside the storm variable is only executing once.
I also tried keeping for loop inside the return function but got an error.

Thanks in Advance

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import LocationMarker from './LocationMarker';
import LocationInfoBox from './LocationInfoBox';
const NATURAL_EVENT_SEVERESTORMS = 'severeStorms';
const Map = ({ eventData, center, zoom }) => {
const [locationInfo, setLocationInfo] = useState(null);
const storms = eventData.map((ev) => {
    if (ev.categories[0].id === NATURAL_EVENT_SEVERESTORMS) {
      for (let i = 0; i < ev.geometry.length; i++) {
        return (
          <LocationMarker
            lat={ev.geometry[i].coordinates[1]}
            lng={ev.geometry[i].coordinates[0]}
            type='severeStorms'
            onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })}
          />
        );
      }
    }
    return null;
  });

  return (
    <div className='map'>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{  }}
        defaultCenter={center}
        defaultZoom={zoom}
      >
        {storms}
      </GoogleMapReact>

      {locationInfo && <LocationInfoBox info={locationInfo} />}
    </div>
  );
};

Map.defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 42.3265,
    lng: -122.8756,
  },
  zoom: 4,
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning the `LocationMarker` JSX in the first iteration of the `for` loop. Instead of it, you should use the `map` method again.

```js
const storms = eventData.map((ev) => {
  if (ev.categories[0].id === NATURAL_EVENT_SEVERESTORMS) {
    return ev.geometry.map((geo) => {
      return (
        <LocationMarker
          lat={geo.coordinates[1]}
          lng={geo.coordinates[0]}
          type='severeStorms'
          onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  return null;
});
```

Also note that you have to add a 'key' property when iterating to render JSX list.

```js
const storms = eventData.map((ev) => {
  if (ev.categories[0].id === NATURAL_EVENT_SEVERESTORMS) {
    return ev.geometry.map((geo) => {
      return (
        <LocationMarker
          key={CHOOSE_UNIQUE_KEY_FOR_THIS_ITEM}
          lat={geo.coordinates[1]}
          lng={geo.coordinates[0]}
          type='severeStorms'
          onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })}
        />
      );
    });
  }
  return null;
});
```

You can read more about this here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

You have two nested loops there, so in order to get the actual array you need to concatenate each loop record, or just use reduce.
Something like this should work:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
import LocationMarker from './LocationMarker';
import LocationInfoBox from './LocationInfoBox';
const NATURAL_EVENT_SEVERESTORMS = 'severeStorms';
const Map = ({ eventData, center, zoom }) => {
const [locationInfo, setLocationInfo] = useState(null);
const storms = eventData.reduce((acc, ev, indx) => {
  const geometries = ev.geometry.map((geo, geoIndx) => (
      <LocationMarker
        key={`${indx}-${geoIndx}`}
        lat={geo.coordinates[1]}
        lng={geo.coordinates[0]}
        type='severeStorms'
        onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })}
      />
  )
  // Concatenate previously collected records with this iteration map output
  acc = acc.concat(geometries)
  return acc
}, [])


  return (
    <div className='map'>
      <GoogleMapReact
        bootstrapURLKeys={{  }}
        defaultCenter={center}
        defaultZoom={zoom}
      >
        {storms}
      </GoogleMapReact>

      {locationInfo && <LocationInfoBox info={locationInfo} />}
    </div>
  );
};

Map.defaultProps = {
  center: {
    lat: 42.3265,
    lng: -122.8756,
  },
  zoom: 4,
};

export default Map;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add all LocationMarker in an array, and then return the array,

What you are doing now, is traversing the loop, and then on first index (i=0), returning the

```
<LocationMarker
        lat={ev.geometry[i].coordinates[1]}
        lng={ev.geometry[i].coordinates[0]}
        type='severeStorms'
        onClick={() => setLocationInfo({ id: ev.id, title: ev.title })}
      />
```

from storms function.